# "A four digit year could not be found" happens when a model tries to SELECT in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to fetch names form this table.

I tried these

```
Category::where('id','20')->value('name');
```

or

```
Category::find(20)->get("name")
```

however,
error "A four digit year could not be found"
happened.

Comment: can you show you model class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cat = Category::query()->where('id','=',20)->first();
$name = null;
if(!is_null($cat)){
   $name = $cat->name;
}
```

should work

however if u use php 8 code will be shorter

```
$name = $cat?->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Category::find($id, ['name']);